# How to convert HEX data into BINARY data?

Tags: python

I am trying to send Binary data using python raw socket.
For that i will do following.

```
s = '\x01\x00\x12\x59' # some binary data
sock.send(s)           # assuming "sock" is a valid, open socket object
```

i have created a DATAGRAM in HEX in by sniffing a network traffic with wireshark.Which i want to send over the network.This hand made datagram is like

"04 f8 00 50 4f 30  fb 47 28 62 a7 6d 50 02 02 00 d2 7f 00 00"

So i wanna convert this above mentioned HEX datagram into the binary format like "\x01\x00\x12\x59".
How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"04 f8 00 50".replace(' ', '').decode('hex')
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
"".join("04 f8 00 50 4f 30 fb 47 28 62 a7 6d 50 02 02 00 d2 7f 00 00".split()).decode('hex')
```

OR:

```
import binascii
print binascii.unhexlify("".join("04 f8 00 50 4f 30 fb 47 28 62 a7 6d 50 02 02 00 d2 7f 00 00".split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

[unhexlify](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) is probably what you're looking for. It doesn't like whitespace, so for your example, `unhexlify(data.replace(" ",""))` should work.